# Import/export JSON add-on in 2.8?

Tags: add-on, eevee-render-engine

Ok there are multiple JSON addons for 2.79 and they work, but I need an add-on for 2.8. Are there any currently for import/export JSON?

Comment: Im not sure if this will help but try this
https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-particleplayer-component